# Looping through the different network share paths

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell script. My requirement is dynamically change the file path in `Get-ChildItem` command. The file path is reading from the text file. Path stored as follows:

```
\\bmcelb\Abbott_GIS_DBA
\\bmcelb\Abbott_GIS_MAR
```

Once I read all the directories' and subdirectories' names, owner, modification details etc. I have to export it to CSV file which should save with same name of the path.

My current script as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Z:\ -Filter *.* -Recurse | Select-Object FullName, CreationTime, @{Name="Size";Expression={$_.Length}}, @{Name="ModifiedDate";Expression={$_.LastWriteTime} | Export-Csv D:\scans.csv'
```

I need to replace the `Z:\` with name which I read from the text file, and the CSV file with current share path (read from text file). How Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to read your file containing path then for each one execute your scriptblock.
This will be something like:

```
$dirs=get-content c:\path\to\filepath.txt

$dirs | foreach {
    #do your stuff, the current path is accessible trough $_ variable
    get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Filter *.* -Recurse .....
}
```

Comment: `foreach ($dir in $dirs) {...}` would be a better approach, because the path must be provided to both `Get-ChildItem` and `Export-Csv`.

Comment: How are you going to supply the share path from the input file to the `Export-Csv` cmdlet?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers the same way as OP : `...  | Select-Object $_.FullName, $_.CreationTime, @{Name="Size";Expression={$_.Length}}, @{Name="ModifiedDate";Expression={$_.LastWriteTime} | Export-Csv D:\scans.csv'`

Comment: Is there any way to save the File with last part of my sharepath.eg if my path like "\\ctsintbmcelb\Abbott_GIS_DBA" Can I save the csv file with the name Abbott_GIS_DBA.csv . I plan to save all the csv file in same folder with above naming concept

Comment: I dont understand what you want

Comment: @Kayasax Using `Export-Csv D:\scans.csv` inside your loop would overwrite the output file with each iteration. Using it outside your loop would collect the data of all input files in one output file instead of creating a separate output file for each input file.

Comment: what about `export-csv -append` ? i dont think output file is dynamic

Comment: The OP clearly said he wants separate output files for each share read from the input file.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
$infile = 'C:\path\to\filepath.txt'
$outdir = 'D:\'

foreach ($dir in (Get-Content $infile)) {
  $outfile = Join-Path $outdir ($dir -split '\\')[-1]
  Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter *.* -Recurse | select ... |
    Export-Csv $outfile -NoType
}
```